# Stata twoway bar graph - how to make the bars actually touch the bottom

Tags: stata

When I am making a twoway bar, I get floating bars, this code:

```
twoway bar b a
```

gives me this:
[image]

I would prefer the bars to touch the bottom, as the code below does:

```
graph bar b, over(a)
```

which makes the following plot:
[image]

because I am actually plotting two different things on the same plot, I think I must use the twoway setting, but it just bugs me that the bars float!

Thanks for any help

Comment: Try `twoway bar a b,  plotregion(margin(zero))` and see if it does what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to post the answer for anyone who might see this. It was from a comment below the question. This works

```
twoway bar a b, plotregion(margin(zero))
```